# UITableView inside UIScrollView not receiving touch at first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am having an issue with a UITableView inside a UIScrollView. When I scroll the external scrollView, the table does not receive the willSelect/didSelect event on the first touch, but it does on the second one. Also having same problem with UIButton which is inside the scrollview.

Comment: why would you need a tableView inside a scrollView? tableView is a subclass of scrollView..

Comment: I am having lots of data to display on screen. I have added three views inside main scroll (Header,body and footer).Inside body view I have display some data in tableview.

Answer (score 2):

- From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html)

> IMPORTANT
>   You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

.

> I am having lots of data to display on screen. I have added three views inside main scroll (Header,body and footer).Inside body view I have display some data in tableview. –  Parvezkhan 2 mins ago

TableViews provide views for Headers & Footers already.So no need to do custom implementation.

Comment: But I am having same problem with UIButton too which is Inside scrollview.

Comment: If you scroll the scrollView then that touch event is being used by the scrollView and will not activate the button as well. If you tap the button without scrolling it works right? That would be correct behaviour.

Comment: ya..but what would be the solution for this problem?

Comment: yes If I tap the button without scrolling It works fine.

Comment: Use a UITableViewController instead, you can create headers and footers and add a button to a cell if you need to (but an accessory view may suffice). If you're not very experienced with them then find some tutorials, they are a bit tricky to get your head around at first but once you've got the hang of using them they are very useful. Good tutorials at techotopia.com & raywenderlich.com